# Making a list of all sublists of a list, starting from the beginning of the original list

Tags: python

For example, if x is [1,2,3,4] then 
     my program returns

```
     [ [], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4] ]
```

Answer (score 8):

That would be:

```
[x[:i] for i in range(len(x) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print [x[:i] for i in xrange(len(x) + 1)]
```